# Run tasks in multiple threads on node.js

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js

I need some help with node.js as i'm a newbie to it.
I have an array of data and have to run functions with that data in multiple threads (using all CPU cores).
In usual for me languages i do create threadpool with number of threads, push some tasks to it, wait until finish, send more tasks to queue.
But i can't figure it out how to do that in nodejs.

PS: i'm using latest 0.8 branch.

Comment: I think you need this: [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)

Comment: event-driven programming is pretty unusual for me now.. Need some help with examples of using with my task..

Comment: Since Node.js doesn't have threads, you need to think more in terms of traditional UNIX programming concepts (i.e. forking, spawning and IPC—Inter Process Communication). There's a NPM module called hook.io that makes the IPC nice and Node-like, rather than defining your own payload format etc, as would typically be the case: https://github.com/hookio/hook.io

Comment: Just a note: a similar question with possibly useful answers can be found here: *How to create threads in nodejs* -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613023/how-to-create-threads-in-nodejs/47631197

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nodejs is built to run on a single process, but you can [spawn](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) other processes. The [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module uses the [fork](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) method from the child_process module, but it's intended for distributing connections of a server across processes and sharing the same port.

I think you want [exec](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback). Example:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
child;

var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]; // your array of data

var n = array.length; // length
var done = 0; // jobs done
var i = n; // iterator

while(i--) { // reverse while loops are faster
    (function (argument) { // A closure
        child = exec('node otherFunction.js '+argument, // Spawn the process, with an item from your array as an argument.
          function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            if (error === null) {
                done += 1;
                if (done === n) {
                    console.log('Everything is done');
                }
            }
        });
    })(array[i]);
}
```

The above is of course bad code and not even tested, but I think it would work. All you have to do is call the function you wanted to call on the array's items in `otherFunction.js`, inside that you would find the arguments in `process.argv`.

Comment: // reverse while loops are faster - Definitely worth trading readability for such huge performance gains. Only on SO

Comment: if you care about speed, do not create a closure inside a loop it makes you lose a lot (much more than looping with ++ instead of --)
http://jsperf.com/closure-vs-name-function-in-a-loop/2

also:
http://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop

Comment: This thing is using `exec`, which spawns a new process. How do you think do the optimizations you mentioned compare to spawning a new process? I think the difference is more like a 1000 times...