# Create different thread in node.js

Tags: node.js, multithreading

can't we create different thread in node.js ?? I want to pool database for every 1 sec in different thread and run main program in one thread. I used setInterval function but, it seems, it is blocked or not acting as expected.
I am new at node,Nice reply would be nice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create threads in nodejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613023/how-to-create-threads-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

This question has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613023/how-to-create-threads-in-nodejs). But to resume, you cannot create Thread (except if you use add-on) but you can run new NodeJs process.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` won't work in this case. You probably need to write a batch script separated from the main program and invoke it using `crontab`. Checkout [crontab man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab%205)