# Node.js only uses one thread, is async broken?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, asynchronous

I heard the reason that MongoDB and other Node.js programs are fast is because they do everything at the same time with async, but when I run a Node program, I only see one thread on my system.  What's wrong?  Have they not finished this feature yet?  If not, how can this be faster than PHP/Apache, where they will run many threads instead of wasting system resources sitting idle?

Comment: Threads have nothing to do with asynchrony.  You need to read http://blog.slaks.net/2014-12-23/parallelism-async-threading-explained/

Comment: I do love the question though.

Answer (score 1):

async is not the same as multi thread. those are two different things.

Asynchronous means that the thread doesn't need to wait for the response of a function call before doing other things.  you can however mix async with multi threading but that does not mean that they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous programming does not necessarily mean multi-threaded.

Asynchronous only means that the data can be transmitted intermittently rather than in a steady stream.

For example, Javascript is a single-threaded runtime that make use of Asynchronous Communication.

Answer (score 0):

You can have [multiple processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613023/how-to-create-threads-in-nodejs) and/or [workers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cluster-master) in node.js too.