# NodeJS Server Start FFMPEG capture of UDP stream without blocking

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I have a nodejs server running on localhost that examines the incoming URL and if it sees a .m3u8 extension serves up the HLS streaming files to the client for playback. I also have the server start an FFMPEG child process to convert a UDP stream to HLS.

An example URL passed to the server might be
http://localhost:7070/udphelp/239.255.1.1:59001/out.m3u8

Right now my server extracts that UDP address, starts FFMPEG to convert that UDP stream to HLS fine. However, I am finding that since UDP streams are "never ending" this is causing a block on the server from serving up the .m3u8 and .ts files for playback.

Is there a way to get FFMPEG to not block the server while its running? Or is there a better server to be using for this other than nodejs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create threads in nodejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613023/how-to-create-threads-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since I didn't care about the IO of the FFMPEG process I used

```
ffmpegProc = process.spawn('../start-ffmpeg', [udpAddress], stdio: 'ignore', detached: true}).unref()
```

the start-ffmpeg is a bash script that calls ffmpeg with some parameters set and i pass in the udp address. This allowed my nodejs server to continue to server the HLS content after I started the FFMPEG process.