# Why node js didn't provide child_thread?

Tags: node.js

NodeJs is a single-thread. When I want to work some high cpu tasks, I can use child_process or cluster to work. Now, my question is why NodeJs provide child_process rather than child_thread? Just it is a single-thread?

Comment: So you're asking why `child_process` is named `child_process` and not `child_thread`, or am I wrong?

Comment: No no  ~ My question is why node provide child_process to create another process rather than provide a method to create another thread for solving the high cpu task ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create threads in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613023/how-to-create-threads-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

Nodejs indeed has a single threaded event loop, each child process spawned is a separate single threaded process.

Perhaps that's a reason why this is so.

p.s. internally the engine is multi threaded - read on: 
[How to create threads in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613023/how-to-create-threads-in-nodejs),
https://softwareengineeringdaily.com/2015/08/02/how-does-node-js-work-asynchronously-without-multithreading/