# Calling C++ DLL in NodeJS asynchronous

Tags: c++, node.js, opencv, dll

I was create a web API with nodeJS and now I want to call C++ dll functions in it. The functions take a long while to executing (Complex image processing functions with openCV) and I want calling them in nodeJS async, many requests most process with this DLLs. how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *C++ Addons* for this, a tutorial is in **https://nodeaddons.com/calling-native-c-dlls-from-a-node-js-web-app/**. It uses the **node foreign function interface ( node-ffi )** to call code from *.dll* directly ( *https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi/wiki/Node-FFI-Tutorial* ). *node-ffi* basically provides *wrapper functions* for the functions in the dynamic library.

For the *async* requirement you can use *Async Library Calls* ability of *node-ffi* ( *https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi/wiki/Node-FFI-Tutorial*, chapter **Async Library Calls** ) or alternatively multiple processes like in [How to create threads in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613023/how-to-create-threads-in-nodejs)