# how to write non blocking code in node js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

here is my code.and its blocking. first its wait for some time then output the result. is there any way to write it non blocking so that output be like expected output
output :
499999999067109000
4950
45
tick
tick
tick
tick
...

expected Output be something like this:
tick
tick
45
tick
tick
...
4950
tick
tick
tick
....
499999999067109000
tick
tick
...

```
setImmediate(function(){
    myCalc(1000000000).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
});

setImmediate(function(){
    myCalc(100).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
});

setImmediate(function(){
    myCalc(10).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
});

setInterval(function(){
  console.log("tick");
},100);

function myCalc(n){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    try{
      sum =0;
      for(let i=0;i<n;i++){
        sum += i;
      }
      resolve(sum);
    }catch(err){
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi sanyaj, Node js is about non blocking IO not non blocking calculations, its not possible

Comment: What happens here is each event will be registered into the event loop, then first calculation will happen (and this is blocking), the respective calculations will happen. After that only the timeout events will fire. If this was a non blocking IO the non blocking may happen.

Comment: @Quentin Can you be more specific about which answer addresses this question? That target is a poorly asked question and doesn't seem to be useful in this context.

Comment: Please follow this [article](https://medium.com/@janithkasun/javascript-what-is-non-blocking-i-o-a2acb5b7594c)

Comment: @E_net4  — https://stackoverflow.com/a/51129437/19068 for example

Comment: @E_net4 I concur, I was in the middle of writing an answer on the *why* and then would've went on to explain the *how* but the question was closed too quick. I think for the OP needs to understand the problem before they can solve it.

Comment: @James Indeed, at this point it might be best to let the OP provide additional information, including whether multi-threading is an option.